# How to create a start screen for my Blackjack game in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, blackjack

I am working on a beginner project and I have extreme trouble creating a simple start screen. I want to have a blank screen with a play button and a title. Pressing the play button should cause the header and button to disappear and the cards to be shown. However, when I press the play button I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: GameLoop.start is not a function 
at enterGame (blackjack.js:30:14)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:16:43)
```

I cannot figure out what this means as `start` is definitely a function in `GameLoop`. This is what I see now when I enter my game:

[image]

The dealer card and buttons show for some reason, unknown to me. Here is the code:

index.html:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>cwd.gameloop.js</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content=""width=device-width, initial-scale="1.0">
            <title>Black Jack</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="blackjack.css">
            <script src="blackjack.js"></script>
            <script src="gameloop.js"></script>
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <div id="start-screen" class="screen" style="display:block">
                <h1>Welcome to the Blackjack trainer!</h1>
                <button onclick="enterGame()">Play</button>
            </div>
            <canvas id="canvas" style="display:none"></canvas>
    
            <h2>Dealer: <span id="dealer-sum"></span></h2>
            <div id="dealer-cards">
                <img id="hidden" src="./Card images/card_back.png">
            </div>
    
            <h2>You: <span id="player-sum"></span></h2>
            <div id="player-cards"></div>
    
            <br>
            <button id="hit">Hit</button>
            <button id="stand":>Stand</button>
            <button id="double":>Double</button>
            <button id="surr":>Surrender</button>
            <p id="results"></p>
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

blackjack.css:

```css
    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        background-color: #225338; 
    }
    
    #dealer-cards img {
        height:  280px;
        width: 200px;
        margin: 1px;
    }
    
    #player-cards img {
        height:  280px;
        width: 200px;
        margin: 1px;
    }
    
    #hit {
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    #stand {
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    #double {
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    #surr {
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
```

relevant parts of blackjack.js:

```js
    window.onload = function() {
    
    }
    
    window.onresize = function() {
        GameLoop.onresize();
    }
    
    function enterGame() {
        GameLoop.start();
    }
```

gameloop.js:

```js
    class GameLoop {
    
        constructor() {
            this.fps = 60;
            this.ctx = null;
            this.cnv = null;
            this.loop = null;
        }
    
        prepareCanvas() {
            this.cnv = document.getElementById('canvas');
            this.ctx = this.cnv.getContext('2d');
            document.body.style.margin = 0;
            document.body.style.padding = 0;
            this.onresize();
        }
    
        onresize() {
            if ( this.cnv ) {
                this.cnv.width = window.innerWidth;
                this.cnv.height = window.innerHeight;
                this.resize();
            }
        }
    
        start() {
            this.toggleScreen('start-screen',false);
            this.toggleScreen('canvas',true);
            this.prepareCanvas();
            this.init();
            this.loop = setInterval(() => {
                this.update();
                this.render();
            }, 1000/this.fps);
        }
    
        toggleScreen(id,toggle) {
            let element = document.getElementById(id);
            let display = ( toggle ) ? 'block' : 'none';
            element.style.display = display;
        }
```

I have been stuck on this for hours.

Answer (score 1):

You have not implemented the following methods of your GameLoop class:

```
resize()
init()
update()
render()
```

You have instantiated the GameLoop class incorrectly. This is the way to do it properly:

```
const blackJackGame = new GameLoop()

blackJackGame.start();
```

Your `toggleScreen()` function is not a toggle function. It is a set function. You are passing the `id` of an element to this function with a `true` or `false` setting. A proper toggle function checks the state of the element and then flips it to the other state.

It is very difficult to understand how you want this code to work, so all that can be done is show you what is definitely not working with this code.

Finally, in your HTML, you have created a `div` called `start-screen`. It might be an idea to wrap the rest of your HTML in another `div` called `game-screen`. Then you can start by displaying the start screen and after the `Enter` button is pressed, you can hide the start screen and show the game screen.

Please note that I have created a CSS class called `#game-screen` so that the game screen is not visible at the beginning.

```js
function enterGame() {
  document.getElementById('start-screen').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('game-screen').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #225338;
}

#game-screen {
  display: none;
}

#dealer-cards img {
  height: 280px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 1px;
}

#player-cards img {
  height: 280px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 1px;
}

#hit {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#stand {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#double {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#surr {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="start-screen" class="screen" style="display:block">
  <h1>Welcome to the Blackjack trainer!</h1>
  <button onclick="enterGame()">Play</button>
</div>
<div id="game-screen">
  <canvas id="canvas" style="display:none"></canvas>

  <h2>Dealer: <span id="dealer-sum"></span></h2>
  <div id="dealer-cards">
    <img id="hidden" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/100x100/?card">
  </div>

  <h2>You: <span id="player-sum"></span></h2>
  <div id="player-cards"></div>

  <br>
  <button id="hit">Hit</button>
  <button id="stand" :>Stand</button>
  <button id="double" :>Double</button>
  <button id="surr" :>Surrender</button>
  <p id="results"></p>
</div>
```